# using clause where within nested structure

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm creating a Dataframe of struct.
I want to create another 2 structs depending on the value of my field **x2.field3** The idea is if **x2.field3==4** Then my struct will be created("struct_1"), if **x2.field3==3** Then my struct will be created("struct_2")

```
when(col("x2.field3").cast(IntegerType())== lit(4), struct(col("x1.field1").alias("index2")).alias("struct_1"))\
                    .when(col("x2.field3").cast(IntegerType())==lit(3), struct(col("x1.field1").alias("Index1")).alias("struct_2"))
```

I tried different solutions and didn't succeed because I have always the same error :

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o21058.withColumn. :
>   org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'CASE WHEN
>   (CAST(`x2`.`field3` AS INT) = 4) THEN named_struct('index2',
>   `x1`.`field1`) WHEN (CAST(`x2`.`field3` AS INT) = 3) THEN
>   named_struct('Index1', `x1`.`field1`) END' due to data type mismatch:
>   THEN and ELSE expressions should all be same type or coercible to a
>   common type;; 'Project [x1#5751, x2#5752, named_struct(gen1,
>   x1#5751.field1, gen2, x1#5751.field1, NamePlaceholder,
>   named_struct(gen3.1, x1#5751.field1, gen3.2, x1#5751.field1, gen3.3,
>   x1#5751.field1, gen3.4, x1#5751.field1, gen3.5, x1#5751.field1,
>   gen3.6, x1#5751.field1, NamePlaceholder, named_struct(gen3.7.1,
>   named_struct(gen3.7.1.1, 11, gen3.7.1.2, 40), col2, CASE WHEN
>   (cast(x2#5752.field3 as int) = 4) THEN named_struct(index2,
>   x1#5751.field1) WHEN (cast(x2#5752.field3 as int) = 3) THEN
>   named_struct(Index1, x1#5751.field1) END))) AS General#5772]
>   +- LogicalRDD [x1#5751, x2#5752], false

My entire **code** is below

```
schema = StructType(
[
StructField('x1',
    StructType([        
       StructField('field1', IntegerType(),True),
       StructField('field2', IntegerType(),True),        
       StructField('x12',
           StructType([        
                StructField('field5', IntegerType(),True)
    ])
               ),
 ])
 ),   
StructField('x2',
StructType([        
StructField('field3', IntegerType(),True),
StructField('field4', BooleanType(),True)
  ])
        )
  ])
     df1 = sqlCtx.createDataFrame([Row(Row(1, 3, Row(23)), Row(3,True))], schema)
    df1.printSchema()
df = df1.withColumn("General",
               struct(
                   col("x1.field1").alias("gen1"),
                   col("x1.field1").alias("gen2"),

                   struct(col("x1.field1").alias("gen3.1"),
                   col("x1.field1").alias("gen3.2"),
                   col("x1.field1").alias("gen3.3"),
                   col("x1.field1").alias("gen3.4"),
                   col("x1.field1").alias("gen3.5"),
                   col("x1.field1").alias("gen3.6"),
                   struct(struct(lit(11).alias("gen3.7.1.1"),
                        lit(40).alias("gen3.7.1.2")).alias("gen3.7.1"),

                    when(col("x2.field3").cast(IntegerType())== lit(4), struct(col("x1.field1").alias("index2")).alias("struct_1"))\
                    .when(col("x2.field3").cast(IntegerType())==lit(3), struct(col("x1.field1").alias("Index1")).alias("struct_2"))



                         ).alias("gen3.7")).alias("gen3")
                    )).drop('x1','x2')
           df.printSchema()
```

Answer (score 0):

Over, `struct_1` and `struct_2` are exclusive, so I recommend you the following piece of code :

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Row 
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

schema = StructType(
[
StructField('x1',
    StructType([        
       StructField('field1', IntegerType(),True),
       StructField('field2', IntegerType(),True),        
       StructField('x12',
           StructType([        
                StructField('field5', IntegerType(),True)
    ])
               ),
 ])
 ),   
StructField('x2',
StructType([        
StructField('field3', IntegerType(),True),
StructField('field4', BooleanType(),True)
  ])
        )
  ])

df1 = sqlCtx.createDataFrame([Row(Row(1, 3, Row(23)), Row(1,True))], schema)

df = df1.withColumn("General",
               struct(
                   col("x1.field1").alias("gen1"),
                   col("x1.field1").alias("gen2"),

                   struct(col("x1.field1").alias("gen3.1"),
                   col("x1.field1").alias("gen3.2"),
                   col("x1.field1").alias("gen3.3"),
                   col("x1.field1").alias("gen3.4"),
                   col("x1.field1").alias("gen3.5"),
                   col("x1.field1").alias("gen3.6"),
                   struct(struct(lit(11).alias("gen3.7.1.1"),
                        lit(40).alias("gen3.7.1.2")).alias("gen3.7.1"),

                    when(col("x2.field3").cast(IntegerType())== lit(4), struct(col("x1.field1").alias("index2"))).alias("struct_1"),
                    when(col("x2.field3").cast(IntegerType())==lit(3), struct(col("x1.field1").alias("Index1"))).alias("struct_2")



                         ).alias("gen3.7")).alias("gen3")
                    )).drop('x1','x2')
df.printSchema()
```

Output :

```
root
 |-- General: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- gen1: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- gen2: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- gen3: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- gen3.1: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- gen3.2: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- gen3.3: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- gen3.4: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- gen3.5: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- gen3.6: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- gen3.7: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- gen3.7.1: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- gen3.7.1.1: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |-- gen3.7.1.2: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- struct_1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- index2: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- struct_2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Index1: integer (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but in my case x2.field3 == 3 so I have to create struct_2. (not struct 2 and struct1) @baitmbarek

Comment: @over DataFrames are highly structured (and strongly typed) representations of your data. Even if your Data doesn't contain any `x2.field3 = 4` at runtime, you have to declare that it's possible and if so, data should be appended to some `struct_1`. Every single possible result field should be declared in the `DataFrame's` schema

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean ? can you explain more ? please? @baimbarek

Comment: In your code, you're telling Spark to append a new Struct column to your DataFrame. In `gen3.gen3.7` field, you define a first field `gen3.7.1` which contains two integer attributes. Everything's fine. But now, you tell spark to append another field to `gen3.gen3.7`. Problem, depending on data (on each row since everything is parallelized) you want to name your structure either struct_1 or struct_2. Spark has to create both fields as common `structure` for every record (DataFrames are not semi-structured like json for instance). @over

Comment: I understand well . Thank you so much . I was thinking about deleting the structure that is == NULL. Have you an idea about how can I do it please ?

Comment: Then you should probably define a semi-structured projection (json) and then let Spark do the job for you

Comment: what do you mean please by creating a semi-structured projection (json)??